# How to call or show table that have column name contains bracket in php?

Tags: php, ajax, database, codeigniter-3

I can't call the table that has column contains brackets ().

How do I call the table and can I aliases the column name?

The table that contains brackets is material detail and the column is Panjang(mm) and Lebar(mm)

My Controller :

```
public function GetDataID()
{

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $cek = $this->list->getDetailBagJob2($id);
    if ($cek->num_rows() == 0) {
        $bagianjob = $this->list->getDetailBagJob1($id)->result();
        echo json_encode($bagianjob);
    } else {
        $bagianjob = $this->list->getDetailBagJob2($id)->result();
        echo json_encode($bagianjob);
    }
}
```

My Models :

```
public function getDetailBagJob1($id)
{

    $this->db->from('opdetailbagianjob');
    $this->db->join('mbagianjob', 'opdetailbagianjob.ID_Bagian_Job=mbagianjob.ID_Bagian_Job');
    $this->db->join('mmaterial', 'opdetailbagianjob.ID_Gramatur=mmaterial.ID_Material');
    $this->db->join('mmaterial_type', 'opdetailbagianjob.ID_Bahan=mmaterial_type.ID_Mat_Type');
    $this->db->join('mmaterialdetail', 'opdetailbagianjob.ID_Ukuran=mmaterialdetail.ID_Mat_Detail');

    $this->db->where('No_Enquiry', $id);

    return $this->db->get();
}
public function getDetailBagJob2($id)
{

    $this->db->select('opdetailbagianjob.*,opdetailbagianjob.Keterangan as keteranganbagjob,mbagianjob.*,mmaterial.*,mmaterial_type.*,mmaterialdetail.*');
    $this->db->from('opdetailbagianjob');
    $this->db->join('mbagianjob', 'opdetailbagianjob.ID_Bagian_Job=mbagianjob.ID_Bagian_Job');
    $this->db->join('mmaterial', 'opdetailbagianjob.ID_Gramatur=mmaterial.ID_Material');
    $this->db->join('mmaterial_type', 'opdetailbagianjob.ID_Bahan=mmaterial_type.ID_Mat_Type');
    $this->db->where('No_Enquiry', $id);

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

My Ajax To call the response in console :

```
function ambilenquiry(id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Enquiry/GetDataID",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "id": id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Gagal');
            }
        });

    }
```

I expect the output is success response, but the response show error with

> jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST
>   http://10.3.1.10:81/gapcalc/Enquiry/GetDataID 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

Comment: usually you add backtick `\`column-name(hello world)\`` to your identifiers, im not sure why do you have these in the first place though

Comment: @Ghost hmm, i try to show the response in console.log, but i got the error when i try call mmaterialtype table in select models, i alr try without that table its works but i need that table. anw as forbacktick dont worry, i use it when i try to call the column in view/html

Comment: anyways try to debug the PHP code first, go to your network tab and see why it yields error 500. while on development, turn on error reporting

Comment: oh yeah thanks! i missed one join table mmaterialdetail in the models! anyways, can we call column that contains bracket? or can we aliases that column? i try to aliases but the (mm) not readed. for the error i upload it here https://imgur.com/a/3nuXyS6
sorry for ask many question

Comment: you can call it directly or with alias, again as I have said on the first comment, use backticks on identifiers, especially with special characters like spaces, dashes, parenthesis and whatnot `\`my-wacky(column_name)`\` like so.

Comment: okay ill try it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what I have said in the comments many times, use backticks for identifiers on those column names that contain dashes, spaces, parenthesis and the like, so that you can have a valid query.

Combine it with the `false` flag on the `->select` method so that it allows you to use raw input and allow those backticks.

```
$this->db->select('
    `mmaterial.Lebar(mm)`,
    `mmaterial.Panjang(mm)`
', false);
```

Comment: thank you! its rly works 
sorry i thought apostrof is backticks
if only i get it from the start 
and seriously thank you man
you are the best

Comment: @AnggaZain in mysql you use `\`` backticks on column names, not `'`. glad this helped